# How to reference JavaScript jsDoc comments from TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, webstorm, jsdoc

I have a large Node.js library that has everything documented with `jsDoc` comments. And I have a `.d.ts` file with all the corresponding declarations.

When I'm using an editor like `WebStorm`, it wouldn't show me any documentation for methods and types because it isn't in the `TypeScript` declaration file.

Is it possible perhaps to amend the `TypeScript` file for each method and type to automatically reference the `jsDoc` in the source JavaScript that contains the documentation?

Something like this? -

```
/**
* @jsdoc-reference ../src/person.js#L105
*/
findPerson(name: string):Person
```

I cannot possibly copy all `jsDoc` documentation from the source `JavaScript` and into the `TypeScript` declaration, that would be way too much.

---

Alternatively, is there any tool that would let us take a `.d.ts` file, and generate a new `TypeScript` file from it that would amend `jsDoc` comments based on some sort of auto-reference to documentation in the source files?

---

**UPDATE**

From what I have found so far, there is no solution for this, so I have started sketching one of my own: [docref](https://github.com/vitaly-t/docref).

Comment: no, not currently possible:( Related feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12630

Comment: @lena That feature request is 3 years old, not likely that it's happening.

Comment: @lena I have started working on my own solution for this - [docref](https://github.com/vitaly-t/docref).